# My right click is being odd with Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My right click is not placing blocks or opening stuff. It is acting like I'm holding down right click instead, until I do a different action e.g. open inventory/attack. I have tried restarting Minecraft, my computer and using different clients (I have also reset my controls).
This is only on Minecraft Java.

Answer (score 1):

That really does sound like a hardware issue, where your mouse lags to fire the 'mouseup' event on your right click.

Here is the test for you: https://www.onlinemictest.com/mouse-test/ You should see your click turn blue the moment you click, and then become paler the moment you release. My guess is you will see it stay dark blue even after release.

If you do: Well, not much to do with that. You 1- Manually do a repair of your mouse or 2- change your mouse.